# Euler formula for nonplanar graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I came across the following generalization of Euler's formula for polyhedra with holes
$$V - E + F = 2 − 2G = 2(1− G)$$
where $G$ is the genus of the polyhedra. I was wondering if this formula applies to arbitrary graphs, where $G$ is thought of as the minimum genus of the graph (i.e. the minimum value $G$ such that the graph may be embedded on a surface with genus $G$ with no crossings). The usual Euler formula
$$V - E + F = 2 \implies E \le 3(V - 2)$$
can be used to bound the number of edges in a planar graph given the number of vertices, by applying the inequality $E \ge \frac32 F$. Can a similar bound be shown on the number of edges in a graph, given the number of vertices $V$ and the genus $G$ (perhaps using the formula above, if it's applicable)?